# How to initiate SMS from django twilio

Tags: django, twilio

All the examples of using django-twilio to send an SMS assume that this is initiated by receiving one first, that my application is responding to an incoming sms by sending another one.

But how do I initiate an SMS call?  I need to send an SMS notifying specific users that a new booking has come in.

This is what I want to do, but all I get is the XML that twilio needs.  What is the missing step?

> @login_required @user_passes_test(is_webmaster) @twilio_view def
>   send_test_sms(request):
>
> ```
> r = twiml.Response()
> r.message('Test SMS from my app', to="+nnnnnnnn")
>
> return r
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio devangel here, I also maintain the [django-twilio](https://github.com/rdegges/django-twilio) library :)

You can send outbound SMS and initiate outbound voice calls using the rest API like so:

```
# import this into your view / controller
from django_twilio.client import twilio_client


# Within your function, use the REST API:
m = twilio_client.messages.create(
    to='TO_NUMBER', 
    from_='FROM_NUMBER', 
    body='Join me and together we can rule the galaxy as father and son!'
)

print m.status
>>> 'sent'
```

You can read more on the REST API client in twilio-python [over here](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basics.html)